# WPF - How to reference a UserControl compiled in another project in my WPF Windows application

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I created and compiled a WPF UserControl Library using VS 2008 .NET 3.5 on a Vista machine.
Then I created a simple WPF Windows application. I added a reference to the compiled UserControl Library. Now when I try to add a  namespace in the XMAL code for the window I do not see my compiled UserControl namespace. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell why you are not seeing it. You can create the reference in xaml manually and see whether it will compile

```
xmlns:ref="clr-namespace:YourLibraryNamespace;assembly=YourLibraryAssemblyName"
```

You may check msdn for [Importing a Namespace into XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514546.aspx)